# How do I disable the mouse wheel backlight on a Posturite keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, backlight, mouse-wheel

I recently began using a [Posturite Number Slide Arch Keyboard (Model EZ-2018)](http://www.posturite.co.uk/number-slide-compact-keyboard.html) on my Linux workstation.  It came with few instructions; none of them dealt with keyboard function, but rather with configuring the various hotkeys in Windows.

On three occasions now I've accidentally used the built-in mouse wheel underneath the space bar.  This causes said wheel to emit an annoyingly bright blue light, regardless of ambient light conditions, and there's no clear way to turn it off.  Even leaving the computer idle overnight doesn't do the trick.

The first time this happened I pressed random keys in combination with mouse wheel actions and actual mouse actions for about 10 minutes, and eventually the light went off.  I have no idea what it was that finally worked.

The second time it happened I unplugged the keyboard from the computer (but that is not easy given my setup).

This third time I decided to leave the keyboard overnight to see if that would work.  It did not.  I could unplug the keyboard again, but then I would lose this opportunity to find the actual solution.

How do I turn off and/or permanently disable the light?  (Answers involving hammers will not be accepted but may be up-voted.)

**New Development**

I got so annoyed that I tried unplugging/reconnecting the keyboard, but this time the *light came back on*.  The keyboard did *not* remember that I had `Function Lock` on, but it did remember the mouse wheel light.

**New New Development**

It seems that after unplugging and replugging the keyboard, the following algorithm worked to turn off the light:

1. Scroll the wheel slowly and watch for the light to begin alternating between off and on (a.k.a. "flickering").
2. Stop scrolling when the light is in the off state.

Note that the light did not exhibit said flickering prior to my power-cycling the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a hammer, use a screw driver.

Open the keyboard, free the PCB, and snip off the LED with a pair of side-cutters.

DONE! :)

Answer (score 0):

Black electrical tape is your friend.  Cover the LED.